# Java - Flushing the OutputStream of a process doesn't send the data immediately if it's too small

Tags: java, outputstream

I'm firing up an external process from Java and grabbing its stdin, stdout and stderr via `process.getInputStream()` etc.  My issue is: when I want to write data to my output stream (the proc's stdin) it's not getting sent until I actually call `close()` on the stream.  I am explicitly calling `flush()`.

I did some experimenting and noticed that if I increased the number of bytes I was sending, it would eventually go through.  The magic number, on my system, is **4058** bytes.

To test I'm sending the data over to a perl script which reads like this:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Perl starting";

while(<STDIN>) {
    print "Perl here, printing this: $_" 
}
```

Now, here's the java code:

```java
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class StreamsExecTest {


    private static String readInputStream(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        int guessSize = is.available();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[guessSize];
        is.read(bytes); // This call has side effect of filling the array
        String output = new String(bytes);
        return output;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Starting up streams test!");

        ProcessBuilder pb;
        pb = new ProcessBuilder("./test.pl");


        // Run the proc and grab the streams
        try {
            Process p = pb.start();
            InputStream pStdOut = p.getInputStream();
            InputStream pStdErr = p.getErrorStream();
            OutputStream pStdIn = p.getOutputStream();


            int counter = 0;
            while (true) {  

                String output = readInputStream(pStdOut);
                if (!output.equals("")) {
                    System.out.println("<OUTPUT> " + output);
                }

                String errors = readInputStream(pStdErr);
                if (!errors.equals("")) {
                    System.out.println("<ERRORS> " + errors);
                }

                if (counter == 50) {
                    // Write to the stdin of the execed proc.  The \n should
                    // in turn trigger it to treat it as a line to process
                    System.out.println("About to send text to proc's stdin");
                    String message = "hello\n";

                    byte[] pInBytes = message.getBytes();
                    pStdIn.write(pInBytes);
                    pStdIn.flush();
                    System.out.println("Sent " + pInBytes.length + " bytes.");

                }

                if (counter == 100) {
                    break;
                }

                Thread.sleep(100);
                counter++;
            }
            // Cleanup
            pStdOut.close();
            pStdErr.close();
            pStdIn.close();
            p.destroy();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Catch everything
            System.out.println("Exception!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }
}
```

So when I run this, I get effectively nothing back.  If immediately after calling `flush()`, I call `close()` on pStdIn, it works as expected.  This isn't what I want though; I want to be able to continually hold the stream open and write to it whenever it so pleases me.  As mentioned before, if message is 4058 bytes or larger, this will work without the `close()`.

Is the operating system (running on 64bit Linux, with a 64bit Sun JDK for what it's worth) buffering the data before sending it?  I could see Java having no real control over that, once the JVM makes the system call to write to the pipe all it can do is wait.  There's another puzzle though:

The Perl script prints line before going into the `while` loop.  Since I check for any input from Perl's stdout on every iteration of my Java loop, I would expect to see it on the first run through the loop, see the attempt at sending data from Java->Perl and then nothing.  But I actually only see the initial message from Perl (after that OUTPUT message) when the write to the output stream happens.  Is something blocking that I'm not aware of?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi. I took a look in the docs and I found this "If the intended destination of this stream is an abstraction provided by the underlying operating system, for example a file, then flushing the stream guarantees only that bytes previously written to the stream are passed to the operating system for writing; it does not guarantee that they are actually written to a physical device such as a disk drive." (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush%28%29) Reading this, I think that the "problem" is really the SO, not Java.

Comment: you should always read the output and error streams using separate threads.  this is a well known "gotcha" of running processes from java.

Comment: @jtahlborn  Tried moving both the reading and writing processes into separate threads and get identical behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't told Perl to use unbuffered output.  Look in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) and search for `$|` for different ways to set unbuffered mode.  In essence, one of:

```
HANDLE->autoflush( EXPR )
$OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH
$|
```

Comment: This did it.  Setting $| = 1 in the perl script caused everything to behave as expected!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perl may be buffering it before it starts printing anything.

> is.read(bytes); // This call has side effect of filling the array

No it doesn't. It has the effect of reading between 1 and `bytes.length-1` bytes into the array. See the Javadoc.

Comment: I tried dramatically increasing the message size from Perl to see if I could force it to in turn flush its buffer and no dice.  Something interesting happened though.  I got perl to ouput 4058 "!"'s before it starts the while loop.  The result I got back looked like:

Starting up streams test!
About to send text to proc's stdin
Sent 4058 bytes.
<OUTPUT> !(*4058)
Perl here, printing this: ..... (java sent it 4058 .'s in return).  

Not all of the ...'s were printed, only the first 7 or so.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any obvious buffering in your code, so it may be on the Perl side.  What happens if you put a newline `\n` at the end of your print statement?

Note also that you can't, in general, read the stdin and stderr on the main thread like that.  You'll be subject to deadlock - e.g., if the child process prints lots of stderr, while the parent is reading stdin, the stderr buffer will fill and the child process will block, but the parent will stay blocked forever trying to read stdin.

You need to use separate threads to read stderr and stding (also separate from the main thread, which here is used to pump input to the process).